# Need to Listen the files in a local directory using spring framework

Tags: java, spring

I need to create java application with spring framework to listen the files in a directory. 
My requirement is,if any file is found in the directory  then i need to process that file and send to some output folder. 
Again if any new file added in the same directory then again i need to take that file and again need to send to output folder.

In simple term, My application should always listen that particular directory and process the newly added file.
I searched in some forums and i found some answers, they suggested to use WatchService,jPoller or JNotify service, but here i need to use 
spring framework to listen the directory and process the files.

Kindly give me the better solution to achieve this.

Comment: Since you also want to process the files. Did you take a look at `Spring Batch`?

Comment: Yes. But is there any way to listen the local directory using Spring Batch ?
If i add new file in the same directory then again my application should process the file .. How i can achieve this in spring batch ?

Answer (score 0):

I would - and have, in a case very similar - use Java 1.8's `Files.walk` method. I half wonder if you won't find anything in the Spring framework because a solution exists in the pure JDK.

Anyway, here's a snippet for using `Files.walk`

```
    Stream<Path> paths = Files.walk( lookInPath );
    paths
        .forEach( ( pathIn ) -> {
            this.processFile( pathIn );
        }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply..
Whatever you have mentioned above is to read the files from the path by using Files.walk. 
But my requirement is to listen the particular folder and if any new file is added to that folder then my application needs to take that file and have to do some operation(My application should always listen the particular folder). I need spring supported framework for this requirement.

Comment: Then you can use Spring's @Async and poll and do Files.walk every second or so, or use a Watch Service, also found in The Files package ;)

Comment: Err I meant Spring Scheduling, not @Async: https://spring.io/guides/gs/scheduling-tasks/